# how to keep the nested navigator stack history when swiping to another stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, nested, navigator

I have made a `TabBarView` with a `TabBar` and each tab has its own navigator stack
when navigating through the navigator stack of the first tab and at some point swiping to another tab
and swiping back to the previous tab, the previous tab navigator stack has reset like it has build again

how to handle this situation
I want each tab navigator stack to hold its history when swiping to another tabs

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution and it is simply just wrap the nested Navigator with a stateful widget and use the state of the stateful widget with the mixin AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and implement the (must be implemented method)
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

as the following example

```
 class NotificationsNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _NotificationsNavigatorState createState() => _NotificationsNavigatorState();
}

class _NotificationsNavigatorState extends State<NotificationsNavigator> with 
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

@override 
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Navigator(
      key: someKey,
      onGenerateRoute: notificationsOnGenerateRoutes,
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }

}
```